# PDFBox Digital Signature using HSM Service

Tags: java, digital-signature, pdfbox

I would like to use pdfbox to insert digital signatures using an hsm service.

I am using the examples here as a starting point https://github.com/apache/pdfbox/tree/2.0.7/examples/src/main/java/org/apache/pdfbox/examples/signature. These examples assume that I posses the private key and passphrase.

In my case, I'll be generating a hash of the appropriate bits of the pdf and passing them along to a service for signing.  With some guidance from this thread's author: [PDF Signing, generated PDF Document certification is invalid? (using external signing, web-eid, HSM)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44196316/pdf-signing-generated-pdf-document-certification-is-invalid-using-external-si) I've cobbled together the following changes to CreateSignatureBase.sign in order attach the certificate:

```
    @Override
public byte[] sign(InputStream content) throws IOException
{
    try
    {
        List<Certificate> certList = new ArrayList<Certificate>();
        certList.addAll(Arrays.asList(certificateChain));
        certList.add(certificate);
        Store certs = new JcaCertStore(certList);
        CMSSignedDataGenerator gen = new CMSSignedDataGenerator();

        byte[] sh = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256").digest(IOUtils.toByteArray(content));

        String hexencodedDigest = new BigInteger(1, sh).toString(16);
        hexencodedDigest = hexencodedDigest.toUpperCase();
        // Send digest to signing service
        final String signedHash = certProvider.signPdfDigest(hexencodedDigest);

        ContentSigner nonSigner = new ContentSigner() {

            @Override
            public byte[] getSignature() {
                try {
                    return Hex.decodeHex(signedHash.toCharArray());
                } catch (DecoderException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                return null;
            }

            @Override
            public OutputStream getOutputStream() {
                return new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            }

            @Override
            public AlgorithmIdentifier getAlgorithmIdentifier() {
                return new DefaultSignatureAlgorithmIdentifierFinder().find("SHA256WithRSAEncryption");
            }
        };

        org.bouncycastle.asn1.x509.Certificate cert = org.bouncycastle.asn1.x509.Certificate.getInstance(certificateChain[0].getEncoded());
        JcaSignerInfoGeneratorBuilder sigb = new JcaSignerInfoGeneratorBuilder(new JcaDigestCalculatorProviderBuilder().build());

        //ContentSigner sha1Signer = new JcaContentSignerBuilder("SHA256WithRSA").build(privateKey);
        gen.addSignerInfoGenerator(sigb.build(nonSigner, new X509CertificateHolder(cert)));
        gen.addCertificates(certs);
        CMSTypedDataInputStream msg = new CMSTypedDataInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream("useless_data".getBytes())); // this is never used.

        //CMSProcessableInputStream msg = new CMSProcessableInputStream(content);
        CMSSignedData signedData = gen.generate(msg, false);
        if (tsaClient != null)
        {
            signedData = signTimeStamps(signedData);
        }

        byte[] pkcs7 = signedData.getEncoded();

        content.close();

        return pkcs7;
    }
    catch (GeneralSecurityException | CMSException | TSPException | OperatorCreationException e)
    {
        throw new IOException(e);
    } catch (SessionExpiredException | TokenExpiredException | CertProviderException e) {
        throw new IOException(e);
    }
}
```

The document comes up as altered or corrupted and Show signature returns the following error:

> org.bouncycastle.cms.CMSSignerDigestMismatchException: message-digest
>   attribute value does not match calculated value.

Comment: Please share a pdf signed with your code for analysis.

Comment: @mkl https://ufile.io/dlgqh

Comment: Well, the signed byte ranges hash indeed differs from the hash signed by the signature container, the former being "543680d14efd4ce99a4a0192d568f12e337b1b61358d2ef108c9ee138db263dd", the latter "E3B0C44298FC1C149AFBF4C8996FB92427AE41E4649B934CA495991B7852B855", no apparent similarities...

Comment: @mkl, thanks for your reply.   Am I correct in thinking that externalSigning.getContent returns the ranges of the pdf that need signing?  Excluding the ranges where the signature will be embedded?  If so, according to my HSM provider, I need to provide them a Hex encoded SHA256 message digest in upper case, and I expect this is where I'm going wrong.  My main stumbling block with CreateSignatureBase seems to be getting a ContentSigner object that can use a private key reference rather than the key itself.  Any recommendations?

Comment: *"Am I correct in thinking that externalSigning.getContent returns the ranges of the pdf that need signing?"* - Yes, that's correct. Your code  creates invalid signatures. To locate the point of failure, therefore, you should add quite some logging. In particular you should log the `sh` bytes and the `hexencodedDigest` generated for it and eventually compare both representations with each other, with the document hash in the signature container retrieved for that input, and with the hash of the signed bytes created by a separate piece of code.

Comment: By the way, I just looked at your code more closely. There is something conceptually wrong with it: You sign the document hash and then try to put this signature into a CMS container. For non-trivial signer-info structures in that CMS container that cannot work as the document hash is not signed as-is but instead it is embedded in a structure called signed attributes, and these signed attributes are again hashed and signed.

Comment: What exactly is the contract of `certProvider.signPdfDigest`, what are the parameter requirements, what are the result promises? Considering its name it is somehow PDF specific, but signing a hash (of the signed byte ranges of a PDF or some other data) is not PDF specific, so what is?

Comment: @mkl, there is nothing pdf specific about signPdfDigest.  It wants a hex encoded sha256 digest in upper case and sends this off to our hosted hsm service for signing.  The concept was an adaptation of an adaptation of the pdfbox example code to get it to work with a hosted hsm where I'm not in possession of the private key.  So I need CMS container signed attributes to generate the hash to sign?  Thoughts on creating one of those with a ContentSigner that doesn't require a private key?

Comment: you don't need the actual private key, merely the capacity to sign with it given a pre-calculated hash and the associated public certificate beforehand.